# UI breaks when changing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, landscape-portrait

Hi I am developing an app which works in both orientation.Its working fine,But when I go from fragment A to fragment B in landscape mode  fragment B UI breaks.But if are in fragment B and change the orientation it works fine,ie no UI breaking.Why would the UI breaks when it is coming from the previous fragment in landscape mode ?If we are staying in fragment B and change both orientation ,no UI breaks.I don't know what is the issue.I have searched a lot but couldn't find the reason.
this is how it looks in portrait mode:[image: this is how it looks in portrait mode]
this how it looks when ui breaks:
[image]

this is how it looks when it is fragment B and landscape mode:
[image]

Comment: Provide image of UI issue

Comment: Are you hardcoding the placement of your images in your layout? Please provide all relevant code.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo i have given  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" in manifest

Comment: Add the code of fragment B here

Comment: I suppose that UI breaks because of the incorrect timing\place\function in which you set column's width.